# twisted web server not ruuning a .rpy file

Tags: asynchronous, twisted

i am a toddler on Twisted .I am trying to run a Twisted web server using the command

```
    twistd web --resource-script=~/Desktop/step/ecdemo.rpy
```

assume that my file(ecdemo.rpy) is located on desktop in step folder

the traceback when i visit the page(127.0.0.1:8080/ecdemo.rpy) shows

```
    <type 'exceptions.IOError'>: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '~/Desktop/step/ecdemo.rpy
```

however if i run the same file with command 
`python ecdemo.rpy` it runs smoothly.

The program simply renders a get request from an http page

I know it is something basic that i do not know but if you could help me get started i would come up with better problems...

thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your shell didn't expand `~` into your home directory.  Try this instead:

```
twistd web --resource-script ~/Desktop/step/ecdemo.rpy
```

Notice I removed the `=` between the option name and its value.  This will probably let your shell turn `~` into `/home/whoever`.

Comment: thank you JP.Whatever little i know is from your site itself. 
help much appreciated